# Editing a record in a text using Java

Tags: java

I am currently having a problem where it gives me an error when I run my code and doesn't update the text file using the ID that the user enters.

Any ideas on how to fix?

I understand that my code does not have a main as call the constructors into another java file which includes my main.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Update {
public static Scanner x;
public void update() {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String filepath = "Item.txt";
System.out.println("Enter the ID of the item");
int editTerm = input.nextInt();
int newID = editTerm;
System.out.println("Enter the description of the Item");
String newDescription = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter the current price of the item");
double newunitPrice = input.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Enter the current amount of stock");
int newqtyinStock = input.nextInt();
double newtotalPrice = newunitPrice * newqtyinStock;


editRecord(filepath,editTerm,newID,newDescription,newunitPrice,newqtyinStock,newtotalPrice);
System.out.println(newID + "," + newDescription + "," + newunitPrice + "," + newqtyinStock + "," + newtotalPrice + " has been updated on the system");
```

}

```
public static void editRecord(String filepath, int editTerm, int newID, String newDescription, double newunitPrice, int newqtyinStock, double newtotalPrice)
{   
    String tempFile = "temp.txt";
    File oldFile = new File(filepath);
    File newFile = new File(tempFile);
    int ID = 0; String Description = ""; double unitPrice = 0.0; int qtyinStock = 0; double totalPrice = 0.0;
    try
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
        x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
        
        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            ID = x.nextInt();
            Description = x.next();
            unitPrice = x.nextFloat();
            qtyinStock = x.nextInt();
            totalPrice = x.nextFloat();
            
            if(ID == editTerm)
            {
                pw.println(newID + "," + newDescription + "," + newunitPrice + "," + newqtyinStock + "," + newtotalPrice);
            }
            else
            {
                pw.println(ID + "," + Description + "," + unitPrice + "," + qtyinStock + "," + totalPrice);
            }
            
        }
        x.close();
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        oldFile.delete();
        File dump = new File (filepath);
        newFile.renameTo(dump);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Changing in the while loop to:

```
while(x.hasNext())
    {
        ID = x.nextInt();
        Description = x.next();
        unitPrice = x.nextDouble();
        qtyinStock = x.nextInt();
        x.next()
        totalPrice = unitPrice  * qtyinStock;
        
        if(ID == editTerm)
        {
            pw.println(newID + "," + newDescription + "," + newunitPrice + "," + 
 newqtyinStock + "," + newtotalPrice);
        }
        else
        {
            pw.println(ID + "," + Description + "," + unitPrice + "," + 
 qtyinStock + "," + totalPrice);
        }
        
    }
```